# typography standards for presenting web based online reports?

Tags: typography, reports

Should the online reports, developed either for internal or external purposes, follow a standard representation method? like, fonts, font size , color of text for heading and body,placement of graphs etc.

We have lot of internal online reports developed by various employees and it looks odd when you look at it all at a time, since each use different fonts, size etc...over a time.

So,

1) is their any reference for standardization for reports?

2) if not, then , what are the factors for standardizing the same?

Comment: You're asking more about *creating* a local standard than if there is a *global* standard that's applicable, right?

Comment: @BenBrocka ah! it could be both as i do not know if their is a standard followed ??

Answer (score 1):

> 1) is their any reference for standardization for reports?

[Edward Tufte's work](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/) is a good place to start to learn about what works and doesn't work when it comes to visualizing data. He won't give you a standard, but his work can form the basis for one.

> 2) if not, then , what are the factors for standardizing the same?

Well, I think in your case, the primary issue is simply aesthetic consistency. I'd hire an information designer/graphic designer to come up with a system that can be codified/templated.

Comment: tnx for taking time to answer!, is it possible to provide a link? 2)so u r telling me to create my own standard? and in general their is no standard for reports right?

Comment: Link to Tufte added. There is no generic standard. There may be standards (legal or traditional) for a particular field of research or  industry or the like, though. So, barring one of those for this situation, I'd say you'd want to develop your own standard (and include those parties that need to be involved...maybe marketing, maybe legal, etc.)

Comment: hey, i dont see any link here.. can u plz cross check? tnx

Comment: Weird. Sorry about that! Link re-added!

Comment: tnx a lot, appreciate it!